# Is the substitution "ss" for "ß" on mainframes due to the SS being the largest customer of IBM punched cards outside the USA?

Tags: punched-cards, ebcdic

When I was a child, my German teacher (in a non-German speaking country) told us that the typed form for the letter ["ß"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) in use in mainframes at that time was "ss" instead of "sz" (the spoken form of that glyph as it's composed of a ["ſ"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) and a ["ȝ"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z#Variant_and_derived_forms)) because the [SS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS) was the largest customer of punched cards on IBM's [Tabulating Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabulating_machine#Selected_models_and_timeline) outside the USA at that time.

When I told a German friend of mine (also working in IT), he said he never heard of this and tried proving me wrong, but there is no literature that either he nor I can find that (dis)proves the statement of my German teacher over ½ century ago...

*Is there any literature out there that anyone here is aware of that (dis)proves this tale?*

P.S. Asking here on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ and not asking over on https://history.stackexchange.com/ nor https://german.stackexchange.com/ as we're just 2 nerds working in the IT industry that are just looking for logic whereas on the other 2 sites, this might be a sensitive subject.

**Note:** No one ever said there were mainframes in the 1930s-40s: I was taught that the mainframes of the 60s used it *because the tabulating machines of the 30s used it and the mainframes were the later version of the tabulating machines...*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs to be moved to German.SE

Comment: Actually, this looks like just the sort of question they like to argue over at https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think it's a fair question, but the OP's incorrect understanding can be very easily refuted by reference to a list of mainframe codepages (@Raffzahn, appended to your anser as a comment).

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd There were no code pages in the 1930s/40s which this is about. Also code pages do not cover what characters are used if a certain one is not available.

Comment: @Raffzahn OP specifically says mainframes, and "over ½ century ago" can reasonably be interpreted as referring to the 1960s by which time there were definitely multiple character sets whether explicitly called codepages or not. I suggest https://www.masswerk.at/misc/card-punch-typography/editor.html is relevant, the picture of a German card at the end specifically omits ß although it has some characters with umlauts. Now tell me that the 029 wasn't around 50 years ago >:)

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd is it that easy to ignore a questions core by picking some random data? It doesn't ask about a 1960s code, that's the point in time *he* was told that explanation, but a reasoning based in the 1930s - or are you implying that the SS was still an influential IBM customer in the 1960s? Get real. Also, the page you point to shows the IA5 interpretation which was defined in 1963 (today ISO 646), which as well predates codepages. What a 029 prints is not of a code page but its local interpretation of a punch card's holes. It's the good old mess of 7 bit ASCII in international use.

Comment: @Raffzahn yes, that's a very good point: SS implies 1930s which is more like a century than half a century. I was reading the question more to imply that there was something institutional in IBM which led them to favour the SS rendition... but OP does say "SS ... at that time" which implies that my interpretation is wrong.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd NP. Back in the days that replacement was strictly user side anyway.

Comment: @Raffzahn I never said there were mainframes in the 30s-40s: the mainframes used that *because the tabulating machines used it!*  (I.E. "It's always been like this")

Comment: Even disregarding the information in the already existing answers, one problem with that story is that it doesn't seem to explain in any way why the SS in particular would be more likely to substitute ß with "ss" than with "sz".

Comment: @SolomonSlow But on Sceptics it would be closed for the claim not being sufficiently notorious. They don't do "I have heard somewhere that X" kind of claims, it needs to be something that you can point to one, ideally multiple, sources for.

Comment: @Fabby That's based on incorrect information: there were German mainframe codepages that had ß and I appended a documentation link to Raffzahn's answer.

Comment: There is a guideline for migration, if the question is valid where it is, don't migrate, even if it may fit better elsewhere.  This question is valid here.

Comment: **Philosophical note:** A statement without verifiable evidence never needs to be ”disproven”, because it hasn’t been “proven” in the first place. … Sadly, this is the prime rhetorical trick that stupid people play: When they don’t have arguments, they just claim to be right and that the other side would have to make counter-arguments to convince them. (Which smart people always fall for, since they are full of self-doubt thanks to Dunning-Kruger anyway.) Just to reject them, wait for the other side to trip up, point to it, and declare themselves the winner. … Please don’t play their game.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The ß -> ss transcription goes back centuries (see e.g. the [German Wikipedia entry on the ß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Die_%C5%BF-s-Ligatur_in_der_Antiqua)), so: no.

Comment: One more thing I found out I was being lied to...

Comment: As a Danish person, I was taught that ß could be substituted with ss, which would have been about 20 years ago.

Answer (score 41):

### TL;DR: NO

---

> When I was a child, my German teacher (in a non-German speaking country) told us that the typed form for the letter "ß" in use in mainframes at that time was "ss" instead of "sz" (the spoken form of that glyph as it's composed of a "ſ" and a "ȝ") because the SS was the largest customer of punched cards on IBM's Tabulating Machines outside the USA at that time.

Sorry, but that's as much crap as there can be. Well, not about the digraphs used instead of the [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)) based letter, but the reasoning (*1).

To start with, ligatures of `ss` and `sz` look quite close and the modern `ß` glyph is in fact based on `ss`. Next, the usage of `ss` and `sz` in one and the same [word nor the use of `ß` instead was consistent](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/8376/48959) in German until way into the [19th century](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3065/48959). It was people like the Brothers Grimm and their 30+ issue Deutsches Wörterbuch (German Dictionary) that helped to standardized spelling after the 1850s.

It was in fact their work that favoured the `sz` replacement for `ß`, mostly due the fact that it helped to distinguish words 'downgraded' from such already containing a double-s.

While the whole point of reverting already became an minor issue with the early typewriters (only such not made for German), it took center stage with the advent of teletypes in the 1920s. Here the all official use (e.g. army, post office) used `sz` for the very same reason. In common text `ss` was more common.

*Thus, a common person will have Spass, while the army has Spasz :))*

And that's essentially the state up to today ... well, plus a of course that piece of **Nazi**-history everyone waits for:

One of their improvements for 'purity' was to get rid of any German script, which of course means dropping all additional letters (like we used to have two different `s` - Greek and English BTW as well). At that point Hitler intervened and ordered the `ß` to be kept. Which ofc. was only a lower case one, so capitalisation stayed with `SS` for next to everything published - all like before.

Oh, and `SS`in case of **Mainframes** is a rather simple one: here were no mainframes before and during any time IBM might have wanted to please the Nazis at all. There were only punch card machines, which had no software that dictated the use or not use of certain letters - even less of lower case, which were not a thing back then.

Also, when mainframes became usable much later on, Basic charsets use was all about uppercase (English) Latin letters. And while lower case (and German Ä/Ö/Ü) were added by the time mainframes emerged, noone was really using them (*2). So neither `ß` and even less a back then not invented upper case variant was used - or replaced. After all, replacement would have meant that they can be entered in the first place. So `SS`is the only usage here ... of course unless it was about storing any processing of teletype messages :))

> but there is no literature that either he nor I can find that (dis)proves the statement of my German teacher over ½ century ago...

Wiki got a [whole page about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#History). But you could as well [listen to this fine English chap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMo4gJIlDeU).

> P.S. Asking here on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ and not asking over on https://history.stackexchange.com/ nor https://german.stackexchange.com/ as we're just 2 nerds working in the IT industry that are just looking for logic whereas on the other 2 sites, this might be a sensitive subject.

Well, it would be way better handled over there and I'll be voting for moving, as it is not IT related at all.

---

*1 - Including the part abut SS being the biggest customer. Germany may have been the single biggest IBM market outside the US. But then again Germany had a few large companies using punch cards. If you try  you may come up with many names - including Ford or General Motors :))

*2 - Well, we for example only added lower case to mask text in the early 1980s. Lower case as input was't added until ca. 2000.

Comment: Good answer especially as it includes a link to the very clear video on the letterform.

Comment: Good answer to a good question, refuting the sort of ignorant crap which far too many adults repeat to gullible children.

Comment: In any event, the list of codepages at https://web.archive.org/web/20120716195651/http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/globalization/codepages.html (reached easily via Wikipedia) contains multiple examples supporting ß (which, as a Briton, I find quite quaint: and I applaud the Germans' relaxed attitude towards it when compared with their Western neighbours' insistence on perfection in all their fiddly little accents :-)

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd The question is about a time before code pages, in fact even before computers (ignoring the D11).

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Like I said: I was a child at the time and have found one more thing I was lied to about.  Took me >50 years to get the truth.

Comment: @Raffzahn Thank you for pointing out the 19th century: that is the kind of stuff I was looking for.  The mainframes used it *because the tabulating machines used it*...  I'll clarify that.

Comment: @Fabby Little clarification, punch cards did not use 'it' in any way. They do not convey meaning, they only store what is typed. Other punch card equipment does as well not do any character handling or conversion beside forwarding holes. If at all it was done by the user of a keypunch who typed `SS` (or `SZ`) when encountering a `ß`.

Comment: Fun: now we have ẞ too.

Comment: Wow, Raffzahn is usually well qualified to answer retro questions but an answer requiring both retro knowledge AND German language, even more so. And, as in the past, have to love a language that call the dictionary exactly what it is, a Wörterbuch (word book?) :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo being Bavarian (and old) might have helped a bit. And yes, that's what we call it.

Comment: Re fn 2: I don't understand what 'mask text' means here, but Multics definitely used lowercase input and output for all of the '70s. (So did Unix, but it didn't run on anything you could call a mainframe until VAX ca '78, _maybe_.) And S/370 _could_ handle lowercase, though most programs didn't use it (and most terminals didn't support), and (at our shop) the 1403's by default had an uppercase-only chain so you had to use a special sysout class that usually took hours to get scheduled. I _think_ S/360 also could, but that was gone before I arrived.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Well, text on screen masks - like `Name   :` etc. And yes, lower case could be handled with any /360, right from the start (note where the FN is placed). after all, a byte is a byte and a character is what we assume it to be. Handling lower case (on terminals) was never a hardware issue (on printers it was). Point is that many mainframe applications sily had no need for lower case (or German letters).

Answer (score 3):

As @raffzahn says, as much crap as can be. However, the story cited by the OP may contain a tiny morsel of truth. According to this article, [IBM 'dealt directly with Holocaust organisers'](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2002/mar/29/humanities.highereducation)

> The paperback [IBM and the Holocaust by Edin Black] provides the first evidence that the company's dealings with the Nazis were controlled from its New York headquarters throughout the second world war.

> Mr Black quotes Leon Krzemieniecki, the last surviving per son involved in the Polish administration of the rail transportation to Auschwitz and Treblinka, as saying that he "knew they were not German machines... The labels were in English...

So the claim that Big Blue had the Nazis as a customer  *might* be real, even if the rest of the story is bogus.

Comment: This is fairly common knowledge, as is the fact that Watson was [decorated by Hitler in 1937](https://www.nytimes.com/1937/07/02/archives/thomas-j-watson-is-decorated-by-hitler-for-work-in-bettering.html), a medal that he eventually returned.  But IBM & Dehomag's German operations have little to do with ß = ss or sz.

Comment: The claim isn't that the Nazis were a customer, but that they were the *largest* non-US customer.

Comment: The Nazis definitely used IBM tabulating machines through their German subsidiary Dehomag, the only somewhat controversial part is whether the subsidiary became fully independent after 1941 or was still in a business relationship and largely controlled by IBM in New York, violating laws against dealing with the enemy. The book makes a very strong (if extremely dry and hard to get through) case that it was.

Comment: @llama There are, in fact, two issues: as you say, trading with the enemy; there is also a matter of being an accessory to mass murder.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine "The Nazis literally copied their race laws from the US." Do you really believe that Hitler took an American law, crossed out the title and wrote " Nürnberg Laws" at the top? If not, could you explain what you actually mean? Either way, it would be helpful if you presented some credible evidence?

Comment: @SimonCrase: Hey, I cannot see any arguments in your comment. Also, I’m not religious, so I don’t do “belief”. … I’m German. What I said is not some kind of secret. It is taught to us in school. And if you go to any country around us, they will probably know this too. … I’m not your primary school teacher. Especially when you made zero effort to actually look it up. Please don’t stoop so low to try to present me with such a worn argumentative trick as strawmen, “Do you really believe?” or “Bring me arguments, even though I brought none”. It would insult my intelligence if I was insultable. :)

Comment: @Evi1M4chine I'm sorry that you've been stewing over this for 9 days. From your reply, I understand that you really believe that Hitler took an American law, crossed out the title and wrote " Nürnberg Laws" at the top. Why would Hitler issue a law in English? Or do you think the American laws were written in German?

Comment: @SimonCrase: Stewing? XD … I just come here from time to time and see who replied. :) … Also, I already told you what I think of the concept of “belief”, yet you ignored it and kept repeating the same thing as before. This means you think you can ignore the rules of a discussion, so there is no point in talking to you, as you will just ignore it again. You’re essentially disqualified. … At best, you are trolling or perceiving a different reality. … Picking up a real history book for once would help you more than my replies. … So have a nice day. :)

Comment: @Evi1M4chine Well, I hope you feel better now you've got that off your chest;-)

Comment: @SimonCrase: You know what? I actually do! XD … Thank you very much. :D

Answer (score 0):

You are likely correct about the SS (or at least the German government and all its services, shall we say) being the [#1 customer for these tabulating machines](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27058571). Appaling how IBM got away with their repossession of their German subsidiary (Dehomag) after WW2.

But the ß instead of ss is a normal German language option, as I know it at least.